# Use Dictation with Earbuds' Microphone

Tags: macos, preferences, headphones, voice-dictation

I have the ~$80 apple earbuds, and it has a built-in microphone which works fine. I've used it for skype and taking calls. In Preferences, the drop down for Dictation's input has 'Line-in", but when selected, Dictation does not hear me. In Sound preferences, 'Line-in' has the full title of 'Audio Line-In Port', so it is 'there'.

So I'm just curious why Dictation won't listen via my earbud microphone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your earbuds have one plug that goes into the headphone socket on your laptop, that socket does NOT have a microphone pickup.

The socket in your iPhone is dual capable, both headphone and microphone connections.

You will need to get a headset that has both a microphone and headphone plugs if you want to use your laptop for dictation

Comment: I have the audio-in port next to the audio out port, would that work?

Comment: Make sure that it is a microphone not a line-in port. Some older and high end macbook pros had line in rather than microphone ports which meant the signal from a normal nicrophone was too low to be useful

Comment: I think that's what I have then, the icon has a purple level, but very low. MBP 2008. Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are cheap splitters you can buy to avoid having to buy new headphones. It's hard to find a good one, but [here is an example](http://www.amazon.com/EZOPower-Headset-Adapter-Smartphone-smartphone/dp/B0046FMRGA/ref=pd_sim_sbs_e_1?ie=UTF8&refRID=0VJRVRPD14AG09NGRZVR). Be sure to read the first review on the product, though - it contains vital info.